# Small building game logic

Tags: c#, game

I am planing to create a small game using C#, so I've decided to create a small logic for that game. I immediately opened Visual studio and started to create some classes to hold on the player's data, so I came up with something like this.  However, I don't know whether or not there is better ways to achieve such thing rather than this.

**The Player class**

```
public class Player
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Player name.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Buildings the player already have...
    /// </summary>
    public Building[] Buildings { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Player money.
    /// </summary>
    public int Money { get; set; }
}
```

**The Building class**

```
public class Building
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The building type, Academy, Barracks, Tower, GlassHall... etc
    /// </summary>
    public BuildingType Type { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Requirements for that building.
    /// </summary>
    public Building[] Requirements { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Needed money for that building.
    /// </summary>
    public int NeededMoney { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The buildings level... should be updated after the building is already built.
    /// </summary>
    public int Level { get; set; }
}
```

**The Building types**

```
public enum BuildingType
{
    Academy,
    Barracks,
    Tower,
    GlassHall
}
```

**Main()**

```
static void Main()
{
    var player = new Player
                     {
                         Name = "SweetPlayer...",
                         Money = 50000,

                         //Buildings the player already has...
                         Buildings = new[]
                                         {
                                             new Building {Level = 5, Type = BuildingType.GlassHall},
                                             new Building {Level = 5, Type = BuildingType.Barracks},
                                             new Building {Level = 5, Type = BuildingType.Tower}
                                         }
                     };

    var buildingTobuild = new Building
                              {
                                  Level = 1,
                                  NeededMoney = 40000,
                                  Type = BuildingType.Tower,

                                  //Buildings the player needs in order to establish this building...
                                  Requirements = new[]
                                                     {
                                                         new Building {Level = 5, Type = BuildingType.GlassHall},
                                                         new Building {Level = 5, Type = BuildingType.Academy},
                                                         new Building {Level = 5, Type = BuildingType.Barracks}
                                                     }
                              };

    //Check whether the player has enough money.
    if (player.Money >= buildingTobuild.NeededMoney)
    {
        //We have enough money for the building so let's check if the player meets the requirements...
        var neededBuildings = new ArrayList();

        foreach (var requirement in buildingTobuild.Requirements)
        {
            //The player already has this requirement... so continue...
            if (player.Buildings.ToList().Find(element => element.Type == requirement.Type && element.Level >= requirement.Level) != null)
                continue;
            neededBuildings.Add(requirement);
        }

        //if the list contains more the 0 elements so the player does not meet the requirements... Print the required things for the building.
        if (neededBuildings.Count > 0)
        {
            //a small counter to print the number of the element.
            int counter = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry you need those buildings in order to build the \"{0}\" : ", buildingTobuild.Type);
            Console.WriteLine();

            foreach (var neededBuilding in neededBuildings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", counter, ((Building) neededBuilding).Type);
                counter++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            player.Money = player.Money - buildingTobuild.NeededMoney;
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully built the \"{0}\" your money now = {1}", buildingTobuild.Type ,player.Money);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry the \"{0}\" needs {1} money to be built... You need {2} more", buildingTobuild.Type, buildingTobuild.NeededMoney, buildingTobuild.NeededMoney - player.Money);
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

I have commented everything out for you to know what is going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to review code like this, because it's very obvious it's not “real” code. But I'll try:

1. All your “classes” are basically just C structs. You should probably add some constructors and make some of the setters `private`. You should also move some of the logic from `Main()` to instance methods on those classes.
2. It feels wrong that you need to have a `Building` to know how much it costs and what its requirements are. It might make sense to have two separate classes for that, e.g. `BuildingBlueprint` and `Building`, or something like that, especially if you can have more than one building of the same type in the game.
3. Array is a type that's natural for computers, but it often doesn't make much sense to have in your object model. If you want a mutable collection, use `IList<T>` (or at least `List<T>`). If you want a collection that can't be changed from the outside, use `IEnumerable<T>` (or `IReadOnlyList<T>`).
4. If you continue working on this, you'll probably need specific behavior for each kind of `Building`. Be prepared to use derived classes for that.
5. Don't use `ArrayList`, it's there just for backwards compatibility with .Net 1.0. Use `List<T>` (in your case `List<Building>`) instead.
6. The loop could be written using LINQ as something like:

   ```
   var neededBuildings = buildingTobuild.Requirements.Where(
       required => !player.Buildings.Any(
           built => built.Type == required.Type && built.Level >= required.Level))
       .ToList();
   ```

   This is still O(n^2), but that probably doesn't matter.

   In any case, you should use better variable names, something specific like `built` is much better than the overly general `element`.
7. Instead of using `foreach` with a counter, I think a `for` loop is usually better.
8. You usually shouldn't print the value of an `enum` (like `GlassHall`) directly to the user, you should instead print it using normal English rules (like `Glass hall`).
9. If you want to subtract some value from a property, you can use `-=`.
10. If you separated your code into smaller methods (possibly on your classes, see #1), you could use early return to avoid deep nesting and code that's difficult to follow. E.g.:

    ```
    if (player.Money < buildingTobuild.NeededMoney)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, the \"{0}\" needs {1} money to be built.", …);
        return;
    }

    // for the rest of the method, you know there is enough money
    ```

Comment: Well that was a well detailed answer... thank you very much and i will take all of your advices into account.

Comment: A further refactoring on no 6, would be implementing equality for `Building`s. `var neededBuildings = new HashSet(buildingTobuild.Requirements).Except(player.Buildings)`

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca I don't think that makes sense here. You need buildings with the same *or higher* level. And that's not an equivalence relation, so a `HashSet` wouldn't work.

Comment: @svick Right. I only realized it's a `>=` instead of a `==` after you pointed it out. Then: `var neededBuildings = buildingTobuild.Requirements.Where(required => player.GetBuiltLevel(required.Type) < required.Level)`. Which suggests `Player.Buildings` and `Building.Requirements` should be `Dictionary<BuildingType, int>`

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca Yeah, that's not a bad idea.